# Downloading files into specified location on client's machine without user interaction asp .Net

Tags: c#, asp.net, download

I have a webpage where user's can select the files from a list view and click on a download button to download the files. This is not a public site. I want the selected files to download into a specified location and if the location does not exist then I want to create the location. I don't any save dialog or user interaction.

I understand that this is a security problem as any site could download files into a location on the client's pc without them knowing.

Can someone give me a solution or provide some knowledge on how to do this? Or can you confirm that this is not possible please. Thanks

User's access the site on locked down kiosks, tablets and laptops. All which need to be used offline.

Comment: If you have control over kiosks, you can do it by installing userscripts / browser extensions / application URL schemes that launch apps (they have elevated permissions because the user installing them can be seen of granting them permission to operate). If you don't have control over the kiosks, it's a security nightmare and you can't do it. tl;dr: Yes if you control the browser.

Comment: Any links to these extensions for firefox or chrome?

Comment: I don't know of any specifically, just that it would be possible to write one.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, this is your setup

1. You have a web sever
2. You have a kiosk which shows web pages reading from that web server
3. User uses the kiosk, while on the web page, selects some files in the list and hits some button

Your requirement

1. You want those selected files to be saved on kiosk or some other PC available on the same network, without having save file dialog?

For above requirement you can do this,

1. Create a folder on kiosk/network computer and share it
2. Make sure web server can access the shared location
3. When user clicks on the button on web page
4. Do a post back on server (using AJAX or regular post-back), then on the web server, save the files in the shared folder and provide a success response to the end user

BTW I am NOT sure how you will be able to access those files (saved in kiosk) using the browser, if that is also required.